Why does detector inefficiency (or dark counts) count as a "loop-hole" in Bell-inequality tests?
Conceptually, I don't see why there is a problem with nonunity dection inefficiency or dark counts in a bell-inequality-measuring experiment.
Intuitively, isn't the point of the Bell-inequality to identify circumstances when correlations cannot be explained by classical physics? How could adding extra, uncorrelated randomness (or lack of a signal) cause this to be a problem? Is the point that you don't know if that noise can be correlated? If so, then why not just measure the noise (dark counts) and see if it is?
I would think that this noise can just be averaged out, no?

I might suggest adding the Quantum-Mechanics tag.

@DrChinese Don't you have enough reputation to add this? In any case, you can suggest edits.

@TobiasFünke Well I have done that before... but it said this time that the required "Add Tag" Comment was reserved for the system (I had never seen that before) after I added a Comment over 10 characters. Oh well... Thanks for adding... :)

Correlations in quantum mechanics can and are being explained by "classical physics". Entanglement is a direct consequence of relativity. At least in my books relativity, both Galilean and Lorentzian, are classical properties of the background manifold. Are the consequences for quantum measurements non-intiutive? Probably.

@FlatterMann Sorry, but this is completely off. Entanglement is a consequence of the mathematical formulation of quantum mechanics, arising from the structure of bipartite systems. It is entirely a quantum phenomenon.

And where does the formulation of quantum mechanics come from? What's the physical reason behind it? Relativity.

Bell's argument assumes that there are just two possible outcomes in each trial at each measurement site. If you map detection failures into those two outcomes—e.g., you pass a photon through a polarizer and the possible outcomes are "detected" and "not detected", or if your Stern-Gerlach detector is such that it randomly indicates "up" or "down" when no particle passes through—then indeed there is no problem. The worst thing that can happen is that the noise will wipe out the signal and you will fail to see a violation of Bell's inequality.
If nondetection is a third possible outcome, and you exclude nondetection events when looking for violations of Bell's inequality, that is a loophole; Bell's theorem doesn't apply. Most obviously, a hidden-variable theory could preselect a random measurement angle for each particle in each trial, and cause the particle to fail to be detected if you measure at any other angle. By excluding nondetection events, you'd be allowing the hidden-variable theory to choose the measurement angles, and it could simulate any measurement statistics, even super-quantum correlation.

A non-measurement error based non-detection is a violation of much more fundamental physics. Non-unitarity automatically leads to a failure of energy, momentum and angular momentum conservation, doesn't it? At that point Bell is probably the least of our problems. Am I missing something?

@FlatterMann Nondetections happen randomly all the time in practice in a quantum world, so I don't understand why "malicious nondetections" would have to violate a principle like unitarity or momentum conservation. Even if they would have to, such violations aren't logically impossible, just implausible. Bell's theorem opened up the possibility of ruling out hidden-variable models on stronger grounds than that. An experiment that shows a violation of Bell's inequality, but needs a plausibility argument to justify discarding nondetection events in the analysis, hasn't really accomplished that.

Non-detection happens because of imperfect measurements. It doesn't happen because of something inherent in nature. Measurement errors do, of course, limit the predictive power of an individual experiment, but they are of no importance beyond that. I am talking about explicit unitarity violations. For all I can tell they do much, much worse than to make a tiny effect in a Bell type experiment. They invalidate the local Poincare symmetry of the physical vacuum, do they not?

I think it would be helpful if this was made to be  more explicit. I don't really understand what is problematic with post selection. Like for example, can you show explicitly an (imaginary) system that is local but gives S>2 because of detector inefficiencies?

This explanation just seems like a technicality, stating that the original bells theroem doesn't think about an additional possible output configuration. If that's the case then explicitly show how the inclusion of this extra outcome messes with the results.

@StevenSagona Each iteration of a CHSH experiment produces an $(a,b,A,B)$ tuple (where $a,b$ are the measurement angles and $A,B$ are the outcomes). At pair-production time, the hidden-variable model samples $(a,b,A,B)$ from some distribution, and one particle returns $A$ if measured at angle $a$ and not-detected otherwise, and the other returns $B$ if measured at angle $b$ and not-detected otherwise. Keeping only trials where both particles were detected, you're left with the original distribution of results, which was arbitrary.

Well, the issue with detection inefficiency (or dark counts) is somewhat in the eye of the beholder.  For those that stand firmly behind the predictions of QM, that isn't much of a problem.  After all, you would expect improvements in technology to lead to better and better efficiency.  And therefore closer towards the ideal QM value.
And in fact, that is precisely what has happened.  For example, the usual Bell test measures using some version of the CHSH inequality (usually denoted by S).
Aspect et al, 1982: The Local Realistic (LR) expectation value cannot exceed S=0.0.  On the other hand, the ideal value per QM is about 0.11. The experimental value was 0.10 (+/-0.02), leading to rejection of Local Realism by 5 standard deviations.
Weihs, Zeilinger et al (1998): The local realistic expectation value cannot exceed S=2.00.  On the other hand, the ideal value per QM is about 2.82.  The experimental value was 2.73 (+/-0.02), leading to rejection of Local Realism by 30 standard deviations.
Both of these groundbreaking experiments (which led to the 2022 Nobel in Physics for Aspect and Zeilinger for these and other works) had the "loophole" you describe.  That loophole being that perhaps there was a "conspiracy" of some type that caused the undetected photons to not be detected, but not just randomly.  Maybe those were skewed heavily in some manner, such that the ones detected did not represent a "fair sample".
Unlikely, yes, but that held out hope for some Local Realists who were having trouble accepting the advancing (and well-replicated) results.  Of course: if there really was something to the so-called Fair Sampling Loophole, then Quantum Mechanics would be flat out wrong on this prediction!  That would be big news indeed!

Not to worry. In 2015, we saw an experiment closing the Fair Sampling Loophole.  The quote below the link is from the abstract.
Experimental loophole-free violation of a Bell inequality using entangled electron spins separated by 1.3 km
"In his seminal work, John Bell proved that no theory of nature that obeys locality and realism can reproduce all the predictions of quantum theory. Bell showed that in any local realist theory the correlations between distant measurements satisfy an inequality and, moreover, that this inequality can be violated according to quantum theory. This provided a recipe for experimental tests of the fundamental principles underlying the laws of nature. In the past decades, numerous ingenious Bell inequality tests have been reported. However, because of experimental limitations, all experiments to date required additional assumptions to obtain a contradiction with local realism, resulting in loopholes. Here we report on a Bell experiment that is free of any such additional assumption and thus directly tests the principles underlying Bell's inequality."
